# How to pass several files with iterative names to an executable function in a bash script?

Tags: bash, for-loop, input, iteration

I have an executable file that takes input `.h5` files and returns and output `.h5` file. I produces several input files with iterative names and I would like to pass them to the executable in a for loop.

I think there is a problem with for definition, I tried different syntaxes for for none of which worked.

```
for input_data_ in Dataset/*.h5;
do 
for ((n=1; n<=10, n++))
do 
./myexecutable -i "$input_data_" -o "output/$(basename "$input_data_" .h)_out.h5"
done 
done
```

I get this error: `"arithmetic expression required"`

The input file names: `input_data_1.h5`, `input_data_2.h5` ... 
I pass the files with `-i` to the executable and `-o` returns the output file. The files are located in a folder called `Dataset`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a syntax error in the for loop.

```
for ((n=1; n<=10, n++))
```

You have used `,` instead of `;`. That is why you are getting an `"arithmetic expression required"` error.

Changing it to `for ((n=1; n<=10; n++))` will fix the error.

Comment: thanks, it works. but now it runs in infinite loop and ignores n<=10.

Comment: It should'nt happen. I have also tested the loop. May be the outer loop is executing infinitely. One thing you can do is to debug. Add this line in the beginning of the script "set -x trap; read debug" and echo the value of n inside the inner for loop. This will run the script line by line and you will be able to know what is going wrong.